# Chaining and mapping kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to get a result from a flow, that retrieves a list from a room database, and then trying to map the list with another flow inside from another database operation, but I don't know if it is possible and if it is, how to make it, at this time I'm trying to make something like this

```
fun retrieveOperationsWithDues(client: Long): Flow<List<ItemOperationWithDues>> {
    return database.operationsDao.getOperationCliente(client)
        .flatMapMerge {
            flow<List<ItemOperationWithDues>> {
                it.map { itemOperation ->
                    database.duesDao.cuotasFromOperation(client, itemOperation.id).collectLatest { listDues ->
                        itemOperation.toItemOperationWithDues(listDues)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but looks like is not retrieving anything from the collect. Thanks in advice for any help

Comment: I can't really answer without knowing what each of your functions above is supposed to return, and an exact description of what you want your flow to do at each layer. Right now, you have a `flow` builder that has no `emit()` calls in it, so it will produce nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `flow` builder in `flatMapMerge` block. For each `itemOperation` you can call the `cuotasFromOperatio()` function from the Dao, which returns `Flow` and use `combine()` to combine retrieved flows:

```
fun retrieveOperationsWithDues(client: Long): Flow<List<ItemOperationWithDues>> {
    return database.operationsDao.getOperationCliente(client)
        .flatMapMerge {
            val flows = it.map { itemOperation ->
                database.duesDao.cuotasFromOperation(client, itemOperation.id).map { listDues ->
                    itemOperation.toItemOperationWithDues(listDues)
                }
            }
            combine(flows) { flowArray -> flowArray.toList() }
        }
}
```